# Subtract result set of 2 queries of different collections in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

Subtract result set of 2 queries, each query on different collection but gives the same result set.How to perform this from mongod console.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that from console. If you need something like that, you shoud ask yourself is your data model ok. Maybe you shoud combine those two collections into one (a mongodb collection can containt different documents, no matter their structure). Then one query would be enough.

Comment: I cannot combine them in one collection because records are expected to grow within the single document and we have a cap of 16 mb to be the max size of collection